# Migrating to Flutter 2 fail

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a project that is developed with Flutter `v1.22.6` and was working great, after updating the flutter to `v2.0.0` and reading the documentation, I've found out I can use `dart migrate --apply-changes` to fix issues that are related to flutter upgrade, By running the command I get dozens of errors and the error ends with:

```
The migration tool didn't start, due to analysis errors.

The following steps might fix your problem:
1. Set the lower SDK constraint (in pubspec.yaml) to a version before 2.12.
2. Run `dart pub get`.
3. Try running `dart migrate` again.
```

What is the simplest way to migrate the current project to the v2?

Comment: Are there any existing analysis errors popping up in your IDE?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yes, but the errors are related to nnbd itself. From the working project, I just updated the sdk to `">=2.12.0-259.9.beta <3.0.0"` in yaml file and these errors popped up. Now I'm fixing them manually because `dart migrate` won't work.

Comment: Just found out during migrating another project that you're not supposed to update sdk constraint first like this hint suggests `Set the lower SDK constraint (in pubspec.yaml) to a version before 2.12.` and then `dart migrate` ran fine

Comment: Setting it back to 2.7.0 didn't work for me

Comment: yes but then it says upgrade your libraries, and when you do that, the lower version throws errors and app doesnt builds at all

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have already migrated to a newer version of dart.
You can't migrate your projects from the new version, there is literally nothing to migrate to.

If you want to migrate your older projects (which are without null safety) to a new version, your dart version must be older than 2.12.0 version.
In this case, consider changing the version in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
environment:
   sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'
```

Then run the command in your terminal

```
> dart migrate --apply-changes
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have following step by step [migrate dart 2](https://dart.dev/dart-2)

and base on your error notification try to set in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  # Works in Dart 2 only.
  sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: My SDK is `>=2.12.0 <3.0.0` and I'm sure it's OK, Also I've updated the dart plugin.

Comment: When I had SDK >=2.12.0 I got this error. When I put it back to sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0", analysis passed.